# how to disable more than one times when a link was click by user in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have using ViewItems() function in An-click='VewItems(id)' to call a method in Controller in Angularjs but it seem not good yet because when user click more time my images which load from Model it will get more image or element which I append to a div much as the amount of clicking.

Here is my Function

```
 $scope.ViewItems = function ($id) {

        $('.modal-title').html('');
        $('#bookimg').html('');
        // Fetch an item from book list
        if($id) {

            id = $id;
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url+id,
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                var http_code = response.data.s_respond;
                $('<div id="loading"></div>').appendTo('body');
                if (http_code === 200) {

                    SetErrors(http_code, 'OK');
                    var book_items = JSON.parse(response.data.data);
                    $('<h3>'+book_items.title+'</h3>').appendTo('.modal-title');
                    $('<img src=" '+book_items.image+' " width="100%" />').appendTo('#bookimg');
                    $('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
                } else {

                    SetErrors(http_code, 'warning');
                }
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                SetErrors(http_code, response.textStatus);
            });
        }
    };
```

HTML

Answer (score 2):

Maintain a variable `isClicked` and handle the callback accordingly.

```
var isClicked = false;
$scope.ViewItems = function ($id) {
    if (isClicked) {
         return;
    }
    isClicked = !isClicked;

    ...

}
```

Comment: a single flag `isClicked` wont be enough since there may be multiple links available for the user to click. your solution will disable all the links if the user clicks on any one link.

Comment: You will have to change the code accordingly if there are multiple handlers. I suppose the OP has a single handler.

Answer (score 1):

Just create an array to solve this

```
var loadedIds = [];
$scope.ViewItems = function ($id) {
    var index = loadedIds.indexOf($id);
    if(index == -1){
        loadedIds.push($id);
        -------
    }
};
```